# can I create svg without onmousemove?

Tags: svg, mouseevent, gnuplot, wikipedia, maxima

I create svg files using gnuplot ( from Maxima cas):

```
Maxima version: "5.40.0"
Maxima build date: "2017-06-19 18:56:04"
Host type: "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
Lisp implementation type: "GNU Common Lisp (GCL)"
Lisp implementation version: "GCL 2.6.12"
```

and :

```
G N U P L O T
Version 5.0 patchlevel 7    last modified 2017-08-16
```

Example file and Maxima CAS code [is here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Parabolic_orbits_insidse_upper_main_chessboard_box_for_f(z)_%3D_z%5E2_%2B0.25.svg)

Such svg file contains multiple lines with :

```
<g onmousemove="gnuplot_svg.showHypertext(evt,'')" 
onmouseout="gnuplot_svg.hideHypertext()"><title> </title>
<use xlink:href='#gpPt6' transform='translate(686.6,831.4) 
scale(0.45)' color='rgb(190, 190, 190)'/></g
<use xlink:href='#gpPt6' transform='translate(686.6,831.3) 
scale(0.45)' color='rgb(190, 190, 190)'/
<use xlink:href='#gpPt6' transform='translate(686.6,831.3) 
scale(0.45)' color='rgb(190, 190, 190)'/    <use xlink:href='#gpPt6' 
transform='translate(686.6,831.3) scale(0.45)' color='rgb(190, 190, 
190)'/
```

I do not want to have it because:

- I do not use such feature
- it stops wiki commons page from uploding svg file. I have manually edit file to upload it.

This file is big ( 5 GB) so manually removing all such svg groups is hard ( time consuming)

I have googled for solution but nothing found.

Questions:

1. Can I create svg file without such commands ?
2. How can I easly remove all such groups ?

TIA

---

Edit:

- gnuplot command : "unset mouse " doesn't work

Comment: XSLT transform the files to remove the bits you don't want perhaps.

Comment: The mouse event stuff seems to be triggered by `key=""` which is translated by Maxima into `plot index nnn t ''` in the Gnuplot commands, where `t` means the title for data series nnn. When there is `t 'foo'` then the mouse event stuff is not generated. I looked at the Gnuplot source code but wasn't able to figure out a workaround. I've submitted a message to the gnuplot-info mailing list; I'll keep you posted. Incidentally pre-5.0.0 versions do not contain the mouse event stuff while Gnuplot 5.0.0 and later versions do contain it. The last pre-5.0.0 version is 4.6.6 according to git tag -l.

Comment: I've updated my answer with info about a workaround, and updated code in Maxima. Hope this helps, seems like you have a great problem to work on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mouse event handling stuff is due to a bug in Gnuplot 5.0.0 through 5.3, which has been fixed by commit 083bae1 to gnuplot-gnuplot-main. You can get the current version via:

```
git clone git://git.code.sf.net/p/gnuplot/gnuplot-main gnuplot-gnuplot-main
./prepare
./configure
make && make install
```

which worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04.

I have asked about a work around; I'll update this answer if I find out something. See: https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/mailman/message/36243715/

EDIT: A workaround is to emit `notitle` instead of `t ''` in the Gnuplot commands. I've modified the relevant code in package `draw`. See commits d535d11 and d2488b2 to maxima.

You can obtain the current version (https://sourceforge.net/p/maxima/code/ci/master/tree/share/draw/gnuplot.lisp) or just copy the one modified function:

```
(defun make-obj-title (str)
  (if (= (length str) 0)
    "notitle"
    (if (> (length str) 80)
      (concatenate 'string "t '" (subseq str 0 75) " ...'")
      (concatenate 'string "t '" str "'"))))
```

Comment: I have ubuntu 17.10. I had to install lua5.2 For me worked : "make" then "sudo make install"

Comment: I have checked svg file with Ghex. It does not contain "mouse" string = OK

Comment: I have uploaded new image and new code : https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Parabolic_orbits_insidse_upper_main_chessboard_box_for_f(z)_%3D_z%5E2_%2B0.25.svg

Comment: @Adam Terrific, I'm glad to hear it works for you now. Have fun and keep up the good work.

Comment: Thanks for your help.